# Cannot find interface declaration for 'classA' subclass of 'classB'

Tags: ios, objective-c

`classA` inherits `classC`, `classB` inherits `classA`, and I have imported the .h file for `classA`.

classA:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#ifndef ClientExecutor_h
#define ClientExecutor_h

#endif /* ClientExecutor_h */
#import "ASOrder.h"
#import "BlueManager.h"
#import "Config.h"
#import "Order+Notification.h"
#import "Client.h"
#import "PublisherCode.h"
#import "Protocol.h"
#import "Thread.h"


@interface ClientExecutor : Thread

-(void)doRequest:(Order*) order;
-(int) doLogic:(Order*) order content:(NSString*) content;

@end
```

classB:

```
#ifndef CashCard_executor_h
#define CashCard_executor_h

#import "ClientExecutor.h"
#endif /* CashCard_executor_h */

//@class ClientExecutor;
@interface CashCard:ClientExecutor

@end
```

If I clean the project, the syntax will miss, however, when I build the project I got the error again.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you have `#ifndef`s?

Comment: You should put your import outside the ifndef

Comment: many thanks. i have solved this problem already. That's because i have import the classA on classD and classA import classD , i make a mistake:intersect import.